# symmetric movement of 2 objects

Tags: axis

how can I move 2 objects always symmetrical? I want to move a right and left wheel of an object symmetrical outward/inward. Icould do it by putting the exact y values on each but I was wondering if there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: You could check 'Manipulate Center Points' (next to the pivot point button in Object Mode)  with the pivot set to 'Median', and scale the wheels outwards on their axle-axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a copy location constraint:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also if you have 2 or more objects selected, you can change the pivot point to individual origins, and apply transformation.  My previous answer was wrong about parenting.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup you could parent one wheel to another. Or parent both wheels to an empty and manipulate the empty.  First select the child object, then select the object to be the parent and then press ctrl + p. The menu will pop up and select object

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to run infinitely, I tried Asyncio, and I tried the threading module but didn't get it to work as I'd have desired, however it will set your wheels to be symmetrical, just run the script every time you move the original wheel object.

````
import bpy
original = bpy.data.objects["Wheel"] #rename your objects, to what you have on screen.
changed = bpy.data.objects["Wheel.001"]

changed.location = (-original.location.x,-original.location.y,-original.location.z) #reversal of rotation and location for symmetry.
changed.rotation_euler = (-original.rotation_euler.x,-original.rotation_euler.y,-original.rotation_euler.z)
```
````